# Convert form created by ng-repeat to json object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form which has similar input fields created by ng-repeat.

```
     <form name="userForm" id="userData">
         <div ng-repeat="accountItem in accounts">
             <div layout-gt-sm="row">
                <md-input-container class="" flex-gt-sm>
                    <label class="" ng-model="ctrl.accId" value="{{accountItem.id}}"><h3>{{accountItem.accountName}}</h3></label>
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                    <label>User ID</label>
                    <input data-ng-model="accountItem.username" disabled value="{{accountItem.id}}">
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input data-ng-model="ctrl.zipcode" required>
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                    <label>Confirm Password</label>
                    <input data-ng-model="ctrl.city" required>
                </md-input-container>
             </div>
         </div>
     </form>
```

This creates a form containing input fields for all the records in `accounts` array. What I want is to create a `json` object containing all the data when user clicks on Submit, as follows.

```
{
  {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "user1",
    "zipcode": "10660",
    "city": "abc"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "username": "user2",
    "zipcode": "10660",
    "city": "def"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "username": "user3",
    "zipcode": "10660",
    "city": "hij"
  },
  .
  .
  .
}
```

I tried many approaches but ultimately they all failed, I'm new to JavaScript and looked everywhere for a solution. *`$scope.accounts` array do not have `zipcode` or `city`. When I click submit I need new JSON structure to be created including those two fields for each user.*

Comment: `all the data when user clicks` are in accounts array. I can't figure out what is your problem! Can you explain it?

Comment: `$scope.accounts` array do not have `zipcode` or `city`. When I click submit I need new JSON structure to be created including those two fields for each user.

Comment: `zipcode` and `city` are the same for all accounts?? Where the values come from?

Comment: Those values, the user sets according to his/her need on the input field. Although when I type something on the `zipcode` or `city` I noticed all the input fields for the `zipcode and `city` gets updated with the same value.

Comment: That's because you use `ctrl.zipcode` and `ctrl.city` instead of `accountItem.zipcode` and `accountItem.city`. Check my answer, What's wrong about that??

Comment: Since `account` do not have `zipcode` how can I say `accountItem.zipcode` ?

Comment: If the user enter any value, It adds that key to object. Try that!

Comment: The JSON structure shown is not valid. If you intend an array, it should use square brackets `[`, not curly brackets `{`. The `ng-model` directive does not work with `<label>` elements. Also `value` is not a valid attribute for `<label>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

I think `ctrl.zipcode` should be `accountItem.zipcode` and `ctrl.city` should be `accountItem.city`. Check this code, hope it helps.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.accounts = [{
      id: 1,
      username: "user1"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      username: "user2"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      username: "user3"
    }
  ];

  $scope.go = function() {
    console.log($scope.accounts);
  };
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <form name="userForm" id="userData">
    <div ng-repeat="accountItem in accounts">
      <div layout-gt-sm="row">
        <md-input-container class="" flex-gt-sm>
          <label class="" ng-model="ctrl.accId" value="{{accountItem.id}}"><h3>{{accountItem.accountName}}</h3></label>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
          <label>User ID</label>
          <input data-ng-model="accountItem.username" disabled value="{{accountItem.id}}">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
          <label>Zipcode</label>
          <input data-ng-model="accountItem.zipcode" required>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
          <label>City</label>
          <input data-ng-model="accountItem.city" required>
        </md-input-container>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Go" ng-click="go()">
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The `ng-model` directive does not work with `<label>` elements. Also `value` is not a valid attribute for `<label>` elements.

Comment: TBH I did not look at his code and just made some changes to help him. Thank you for this comment. @georgeawg

Answer (score 0):

> Add form submit

```
<form name="userForm" id="userData" ng-submit="mySubmitFunction">
...
</form>
```

> On your angularjs app code

```
$scope.mySubmitFunction = function(){
    var yourJson = angular.toJson($scope.accounts);
    console.log(yourJson);
}
```

or if you want to change structure between `accounts` and your final json

```
$scope.mySubmitFunction = function(){
    // Create array who will store accounts with new structure
    var accountsForJson = [];
    // Loop on each existing account
    angular.forEach($scope.accounts, function(account, i) {
        // Create new structure for one account
        accountForJson = {
          id : account.id,
          username : account.username,
          zipcode : account.zipcode,
          city: account.city
        }
        // Add account with new structure into array
        accountsForJson.push(accountForJson);
    });
    var yourJson = angular.toJson(accountsForJson);
    console.log(yourJson);
}
```

Comment: `ng-model` should bind new value to array `$scope.accounts`, as long as your binding it with `accountItem`. Try to replace `ctrl` by `accountItem`

Comment: Although when I type something on the `zipcode` or `city` I noticed all the input fields for the `zipcode` and `city` gets updated with the same value. Why is that?

Comment: When you use ng-model, remove `value="..."`. And use `ng-model` instead of `data-ng-model`. As sayed @georgeawg, remove `ng-model` and `value` on first label tag, if you want to send back none displayed data, use `input type="hidden"`